# How to Fix ClassCastException in Android Application?

Tags: android

Here is the Error
from My Logcat :

> Here is the Complete Source Code : https://pastebin.com/MMMybRd0
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:MainScreenTeacher cannot be cast to MainScreen at FragmentHome.onAttach(FragmentHome.java:176)

FragmentHome.java

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemListener {
    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    View itemView;
    private LinearLayout busDirectory, absentDirectory;
    private SharedPreferences pref = null;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    MainScreen activity;
    private List<SettingProfileItem> students;
    private LoadingView load;
    private FragmentHomeListener fragmentHomeListener;
    private String schoolIdSelected;
    private String studentlIdSelected;
    private String fees_url = "";

    public FragmentHome() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Util.setSelectedLang(getActivity());

    }

    public interface FragmentHomeListener {

        void onSettingsHomeClicked();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        fragmentHomeListener = (FragmentHomeListener) getActivity();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = (MainScreen) context;

    }
```

And Here is my MainScreen.java :

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity
        implements RecyclerViewAdapterBottom.ItemListener, FragmentHome.FragmentHomeListener,
        FragmentSettingProfile.SettingsFragmentListener {
    String KEY_ADS_STR = "ads_str_json";
    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    //    String strURLAdv = "http://ws.schoolzoneapp.com/vzons.asmx/getVzonsAdvertisementJsn";
    String strURLUpdate = "http://ws.schoolzoneapp.com/vzons.asmx/updateAppUserLog";
    String[] boomMenuItems;
    int[] boomMenuDrawables;
    BoomMenuButton bmb;


    HashMap<String, Integer> HashMapForLocalRes ;



    private String strAdsJson = null;
    ModelAdv modelAdv;
    private SliderLayout imageSlider;
    LinearLayout tab_menu;
    Button btnHome;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList arrayList;
    public RecyclerViewAdapterBottom adapter;
    HashMap<String, String> url_maps_desc;
    public ImageView tool_imgBack, tool_imgShare, breaking_news;
    private CircleImageView txt_float;
    public TextView tool_txtTitle, txtPowered, tv_student_setting, toolShop, toolAdress;
    public CircleImageView tv_student;
    public RelativeLayout toolbar_layout;

    private int xDelta;
    private int yDelta;
    private ViewGroup mainLayout;
    public Menu mainMenu;
    public boolean showPaymentView;

    private SharedPreferences pref = null;
    private ArrayList<SettingProfileItem> students;
    private LoadingView load;

    private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    private ConnectivityReciever connectReciever;


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (strAdsJson != null) outState.putString(KEY_ADS_STR, strAdsJson);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            strAdsJson = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_ADS_STR);
        }
        AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(this);
        Fresco.initialize(this);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        initView();
```

Here is my MainScreenTeacher.java :

```
public class MainScreenTeacher extends AppCompatActivity
     {
String KEY_ADS_STR = "ads_str_json";
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
//    String strURLAdv = "http://ws.schoolzoneapp.com/vzons.asmx/getVzonsAdvertisementJsn";
String strURLUpdate = "http://ws.schoolzoneapp.com/vzons.asmx/updateAppUserLog";
String[] boomMenuItems;
int[] boomMenuDrawables;
BoomMenuButton bmb;


HashMap<String, Integer> HashMapForLocalRes ;



private String strAdsJson = null;
ModelAdv modelAdv;
private SliderLayout imageSlider;
LinearLayout tab_menu;
Button btnHome;
NavigationView navigationView;
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList arrayList;
public RecyclerViewAdapterBottom adapter;
HashMap<String, String> url_maps_desc;
public ImageView tool_imgBack, tool_imgShare, breaking_news;
private CircleImageView txt_float;
public TextView tool_txtTitle, txtPowered, tv_student_setting, toolShop, toolAdress;
public CircleImageView tv_student;
public RelativeLayout toolbar_layout;

private int xDelta;
private int yDelta;
private ViewGroup mainLayout;
public Menu mainMenu;
public boolean showPaymentView;

private SharedPreferences pref = null;
private ArrayList<SettingProfileItem> students;
private LoadingView load;

private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
private ConnectivityReciever connectReciever;


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (strAdsJson != null) outState.putString(KEY_ADS_STR, strAdsJson);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        strAdsJson = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_ADS_STR);
    }
    AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(this);
    Fresco.initialize(this);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen_teacher);
    initView();
```

Here is ActivityFragmentHomeSecond.java

```
public class ActivityFragmentHomeSecond extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemListener {
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
View itemView;
private LinearLayout busDirectory, absentDirectory;
private SharedPreferences pref = null;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList arrayList;
MainScreenTeacher activity;

private List<SettingProfileItem> students;
private LoadingView load;
private ActivityFragmentHomeSecondListener activityFragmentHomeSecondListener;
private String schoolIdSelected;
private String studentlIdSelected;
private String fees_url = "";

public ActivityFragmentHomeSecond() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Util.setSelectedLang(getActivity());

}

public interface ActivityFragmentHomeSecondListener {

    void onSettingsHomeClicked();

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    activityFragmentHomeSecondListener = (ActivityFragmentHomeSecondListener) getActivity();

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = (MainScreenTeacher) context;

}
```

Please Help me Fix the Error, it will be very Much Helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which activity you have opened FragmentHome

Comment: it is the default screen(First Screen) when the  App opens

Comment: What do you mean by First Screen? Specify the name of activity like MainActivity.java. and you have not posted the full code in activity. Post the full activity code.

Comment: Full code exceeds the Limits and the Activity Name is MainScreen.java

Answer (score 1):

Your activity which open **FragmentHome** is **MainScreen** ( or maybe both of them).in your onAttach,you cast your activity to ** MainScreenTeacher** and make it crash.Try to check like this if(activity instanceOf **MainScreenTeacherActivity**) ->  cast it to **MainScreenTeacherActivity** else if( activity instanace of **MainScreenActivity**) -> cast it to **MainScreenActivity**

Comment: Trying it. Thanks for the Help

Comment: @Zibran you'r welcome.if it work or have any prob,please reply

Comment: Now i got this Error :   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference .  How can i fix this , please

Comment: and dont need to cast like the previous comment anyway , just context instanceOf ...

Comment: This is how i wrote  on FragmentHome.java     :  @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
      //  activity = (MainScreen) context;

        if ( activity instanceof MainScreen){
            activity = (MainScreen) context;
        }
        else{

            activitys = (MainScreenTeacher) context;
        }

    }

Comment: @Zibran and if it not work too,edit your question and post all of your code relate to MainScreenTeacher ,MainScreen,Fragment and your manifest

Comment: FragmentHomeSecond is till the same :  @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = (MainScreenTeacher) context;
       
    }

Comment: omg,huge mistake.do like this  
public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof AbcActivity) {
            activitys = (MainScreenTeacher) context;
        } ...

Comment: you must understand what u face ClassCastException.You are trying to cast the context to wrong type of Activity.In your case, you cast MainActivity to MainActivityTeacher.so you need to check what type of your activity is to cast your activity to exact type of activity

Comment: should i post the Complete code and can you please have a look at it Please

Comment: @Zibran sure,as i mention above,edit your question and post all of your code relate to MainScreenTeacher ,MainScreen,Fragment and your manifest

Comment: Here is the Code friend. The limit was exceeding so , i have this link :https://pastebin.com/MMMybRd0

Comment: @Zibran do you have skype or anything same like that? it really hard to comment alot like this

Comment: can u come on AnyDesk ?

Comment: for sure,on my free time

Comment: please let me know the time so i can be also available